# extend the width of the div base from the specified width without sizing the table td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

below is my snippet, what I'm trying to achieve is extend the width base on its given width (600px, as you can see there is a div that has been given a width of 600px) without sizing its container (td, as you can see the td is expanding also base on its child div that has a 600px width which I dont want). I want the div that has a 600px width to be align with the td's container that was under aug and sep, is there any way to achieve that?

```css
#table_roadmap th, #table_roadmap td {
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

#table_roadmap thead {
  background-color: #ededed;
}

#table_roadmap th:first-child {
  background-color: #40b649;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#table_roadmap th {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#table_roadmap tbody tr td:first-child {
  background-color: #40b649 !important;
  color: #ffffff !important;
  font-weight: 700 !important;
  width: 200px !important;
}

#table_roadmap tbody td {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
}

#table_roadmap .roadmap_card_main {
  padding: 3px 5px;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 3px;
  background-color: green;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<table id="table_roadmap" class="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <th>Projects</th>
    <th>Jan</th>
    <th>Feb</th>
    <th>Mar</th>
    <th>Apr</th>
    <th>May</th>
    <th>Jun</th>
    <th>Jul</th>
    <th>Aug</th>
    <th>Sep</th>
    <th>Oct</th>
    <th>Nov</th>
    <th>Dec</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Project 1
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>
      <div class="roadmap_card_main extend clear bg_green">Card title test 1</div>
      <div class="roadmap_card_main extend clear bg_green" style="position: relative; width: 600px;">Card title test 1</div>
    </td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Project 2</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>
      <div class="roadmap_card_main extend clear bg_green">Card title test 1</div>
    </td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Project 3
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>
      <div class="roadmap_card_main extend clear bg_green">Card title test 1</div>
    </td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bug Checking</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>
      <div class="roadmap_card_main extend clear bg_green">Card title test 1</div>
    </td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you mean that it should [span](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp)?

Comment: yes thats way more to say it.

Comment: Do you want that as an answer?

Comment: no. i mean to span is the div that has a specified width